# What is difference between `SkuType.INAPP` and 'SkuType.SUBS` in `In app purchase`

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I want know the actual meaning of `SkuType.INAPP` and `SkuType.SUBS`

When to use `SkuType.INAPP` and When to use `SkuType.SUBS`

Comment: SkuType.INAPP used for In "App Purchases" and SkuType.SUBS for "Subscriptions." refer this link. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Query

Comment: Thanks you @TakeInfo now i understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKU.INAPP means that the app contains one time purchases, which after consuming you can purchase again at your own ease and choice.
Like purchasing nitrox for car in a car game, once you consumed if you wish to purchase again you can.

SKU.SUBS means that the app contains subscription based purchases for example,
a music app with weekly, monthly, quarterly or yearly based subscription.
User can choose any of the plan to continue using the premium features. once his plan ends he has to pay again for continuation. Best example is GAANA music app that is subscription based.